# Are there any airliners not made by Airbus or Boeing?

Tags: airliner, boeing, airbus, airlines

Are there any commonly used passenger aircraft larger than regional jets (100+ seats) that aren't Boeing or Airbus?

If so, what are they and where are they used?

Comment: The KLM (and cityhopper) fleet consists of Fokkers, Embraers, and McDonnell Douglases.  I think they used to have Bombardiers as well.

Comment: Antonov An-158 is capable of 99 passengers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-148

Comment: See: [List of aircraft manufacturers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_by_date_and_usage_category).

Comment: ATR 72-600 for one: http://www.atraircraft.com/products/list.html

Comment: ATR-72, any model, doesn't offer 100 or more seats.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Ignoring companies that used to exist but are now bankrupt/merged into Airbus or Boeing, you have companies from countries that aren't historically too friendly with the US and Western Europe. For instance, Tupolev makes the [Tu-204](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-204), which is currently in production and seats over 175 passengers. The Ilyushin-designed [Il-96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-96) is a widebody in current use some places (Russia, Cuba). Before the Cold War ended, Russia had more indigenous airliners; Aeroflot now largely uses Boeings and Airbuses, but there are still Russian aircraft that see use.

In addition, you have newer manufacturers starting to enter the market: Bombardier with their [CSeries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_CSeries), Comac (in China) with their [C919](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comac_C919) (in development), and Irkut with their [MC-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irkut_MC-21) (in development). Embraer makes [planes of more than 100 seats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_E-Jet_family) (although they're shorter-range, and you might consider them regional jets).

Comment: And apart from the Russian ones there's also Bombardier and Embraer.

Comment: I think Fokker with the Fokker 100 and BAe with the 146 could be considered small airliner manufacturers of the past with many aircraft still in service.

Comment: Lockheed was a notable airliner maker from years past, not bankrupt, not merged with Boeing or Airbus, but they left the civil market years ago. The OP's 100 seat threshold cuts off a lot of Embraer, Bombardardier, ATR and Beech products that are still making money for their owners, and are very visible at any airport. I still see Dassault Falcon 20s hauling frieght, and brand new Cessna 208 turbo Caravans. Not to mention de Havilland Canada Otters, Twin Otters. Remember, the DC-3 was 21 passengers and 4 or 5 crew.

Comment: Four and a half years later, turns out that Bombardier C Series... is an Airbus. I guess they couldn't do it on their own.

Answer (score 28):

Being used but out of production:

- Ilyushin Il-62 (up to 195 seats): last one built in 2010. Totally built 287, 13 remain in service
- Tupolev Tu-154 (up to 176 seats): last one built in 2013. Totally built 923, 61 remain in service
- Ilyushin Il-86 (up to 350 seats): last one built in 1995, since 2011 only in military use. Totally built 106, 4 remain in service
- Ilyushin Il-18 (up to 120 seats): last one built in 1985, but still in use by several airlines. Totally built 678 (other sources say 850+), 92 remain in service
- Yakovlev Yak-42 (100/120 seats): last one built in 2003, still in use. Totally built 187, 55 remain in service

In production:

- Ilyushin Il-96 (300/436 seats), the 436-seat variant was never built, but freight variant can be converted to use 436 seats upon customer's request. Totally built 28 (incl freght variant), 15 remain in service
- Tupolev Tu-204 (up to 210 seats). Totally built 76, 46 remain in active service.
- Sukhoi SSJ-100 (98-108 seats). Totally built 77, 60 in active service
- Antonov An-158 (up to 99 seats). Totally built 6 (excluding the An-148 variant which has less seats), all 6 in active service.

Comment: This is a good summary of the Russian aircraft, but misses all of the others.

Answer (score 11):

Boeing = Historic Boeing, not McDonnell Douglas, or plain Douglas 
Airbus = Historic Airbus. 
 
Commonly used= ?

A reputable source would be 
http://www.airliners.net/aircraft-data/
From there and comments here, I have edited the following list of manufacturers, for a concise answer, and below that, a list of the aircraft which I believe have more than 100 seats, or can be configured with 100 or more seats, and are in revenue service today, 2015:

**Aircraft  Manufacturers**

1. Antonov
2. Bombardier
3. British Aerospace/AVRO
4. Douglas, McDonnell-Douglas
5. Embraer
6. Fokker
7. Ilyushin
8. Sukhoi
9. Tupolev
10. Yakovlev

**Aircraft  Type**

Antonov An-124 Ruslan   Heavylift freighter 
Antonov An-140 New! Turboprop regional airliner 
Antonov An-225 Mriya    Extra-Large cargo aircraft

Bombardier CRJ-1000 (& C-100, C-300, when deliveries start)

BAE Systems Avro RJX100     Regional airliner 
British Aerospace Avro RJ85/100     Regional airliner 
British Aerospace BAe-146-200 &-300     Regional jet airliner 
 
Douglas DC-7    Piston engine airliner and freighter 
Douglas DC-8-60/70  Long range medium capacity airliner and freighter

Embraer ERJ-195      108 seat regional airliner

Fokker 100  100 seat regional jet

Ilyushin Il-18  Medium range turboprop airliner 
Ilyushin Il-62  Medium to long range medium capacity airliner 
Ilyushin Il-76  Medium to long range freighter 
Ilyushin Il-86  Medium range widebody airliner 
Ilyushin Il-96-300  Long range widebody airliner 
Ilyushin Il-96M & Il-96T    Long range widebody airliner and freighter

McDonnell Douglas DC-10 & Boeing MD-10  Medium to long range widebody airliner  
McDonnell Douglas DC-9-40/50    Short to medium range airliners 
McDonnell Douglas MD-11     Long range widebody airliner 
McDonnell Douglas MD-81/82/83/88    Short to medium range airliner 
McDonnell Douglas MD-87     Short to medium range airliner 
McDonnell Douglas MD-90     Short to medium range airliner

Sukhoi Superjet SSJ-100     Regional jet airliner

Tupolev Tu-154  Medium range airliner 
Tupolev Tu-204 & Tu-214     Medium range airliner

Yakovlev Yak-42     Short range airliner

**Once common, now mostly or all retired:**

Aerospatiale-British Aerospace Concorde     Medium range supersonic airliner

Antonov An-22 Antei     Large capacity turboprop freighter

Avions Marcel Dassault (AMD) Mercure

BAC 111 One-Eleven -500. Short haul airliner

Canadair CL-44 & Yukon  Medium to long range airliner and freighter

Convair 880 and 990

De Havilland Comet   Medium range airliner

Douglas DC-6    Piston engined airliner and freighter 
Douglas DC-8-10/20/30/40/50     Medium to long range airliner and freighter

Hawker Siddley Trident

Lockheed 1049 Super Constellation & 1649 Starliner 
Lockheed L-100 Hercules     Medium range freighter 
Lockheed L-1011 TriStar 1/50/100/150/200/250    Medium to long range widebody airliner 
Lockheed L-1011 TriStar 500     Long range widebody airliner 
Lockheed L-188 Electra  Turboprop airliner and freighter

McDonnell Douglas DC-9-30   Short range airliners

Sud SE-210 Caravelle    Short range airliner

Tupolev Tu-104A Medium to long range airliner 
Tupolev TU-114  long range airliner 
Tupolev Tu-334  Short to medium range airliner prototype

Vickers VC10    Medium to long range airliner

**These are the Boeing and Airbus planes excluded:**

Airbus A300-600     Medium range widebody airliner 
Airbus A300B2/B4    Medium range widebody airliner 
Airbus A310     Medium to long range widebody airliner 
Airbus A318     100 seat regional airliner 
Airbus A319     Medium range airliner 
Airbus A320     Short to medium range airliner 
Airbus A321     Short to medium range narrowbody airliner 
Airbus A330-200     Long range widebody airliner 
Airbus A330-300     Large capacity medium to long range airliner 
Airbus A340-200/300     Long range widebody airliner 
Airbus A340-500/600     Long range widebody airliners 
Airbus A380     High capacity, long range, twindeck, widebody airliner

Boeing 707  Medium to long range airliner and freighter 
Boeing 717  Short to medium range airliner 
Boeing 720  Medium range narrowbody airliner 
Boeing 727  Short to medium range narrowbody airliner 
Boeing 737 Short to medium range narrowbody airliner 
Boeing 747  Long range high capacity widebody airliner 
Boeing 747SP    Long range high capacity widebody airliner 
Boeing 757 Medium range narrowbody airliner 
Boeing 767  Medium to long range widebody airliner 
Boeing 777  Long range high capacity widebody airliner 
Boeing 787-8 Dreamliner     Long range widebody airliner

Boeing C-97 Stratofreighter     Freighter

Comment: You forgot to add SSJ-100 (Sukhoi SuperJet - 100) by Sukhoi Civil Aircrafts

Comment: VC-10 and Trident are **"commonly used"**? I really would like to buy a ticket! Not speaking about the comet!

Comment: Could you please avoid such a lenghty list and lump together the relevant manufacturers?

Comment: @VladimirF: Note that the VC-10 and Trident are under the heading "Once common, now mostly or all retired".

Comment: But that heading is *really* hard to find without any formatting in this dump of all non-small  airliners in history.

Comment: If you're going to be exhaustive, might as well include Bombardier. They make tons of the regional jets that are at least very common here in the U.S. (the CRJs, for example.)

Comment: @Vladimir F - sorry about formatting. Better now? This is hardly a dump of all non-small airliners in history, the 100 seat limit removes a lot of respectable airliners that weren't considered 'small' at the time.

Comment: How on Earth would u put 100 ppl into An-140?

Answer (score 6):

The MD-80 series is still in fairly widespread use, and it wasn't made by Boeing or Airbus either.  The MD-11 is getting harder to find in passenger service, although it's still used for cargo.

Comment: My mind lumps that in as a Boeing ;)

Comment: For the benefit of readers who don't know this, McDonnell Douglas, maker of the MD-80 series, merged with Boeing in 1997.  Airplanes made before the merger are still in service, so whether to classify these as Boeing or not would be a question of definition.

Comment: Lots of DC-10s (or converted 'MD-10s') still in cargo service, too. They only exited scheduled passenger service a year or two ago, IIRC. I wouldn't be surprised if there are still some DC-9s in passenger service, too (even Delta was flying them up until a couple of years ago.)

Answer (score 4):

Bombardier make regional jets but their new [C series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_CSeries) is a 737/A320 class 80-120 seat aircraft

Comment: Although, 80-120 seats isn't really "737 class" in the context of recent 737s. The most recent one (the -900ER) carries 180 passengers in a 3-class configuration. 120 seats is more like DC-9/717 class.

Comment: I meant it was a small airliner rather a commuter jet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , of course.
Tupolev, Antonov, Douglas(I thinks at least they made earlier) and Ilyushin have made many.
While Boeing and Airbus are the most common, Russia, China , India etc. do use (or may be used) other airlines.

Comment: I think there are also some planes made by other companies that were military air planes earlier. But I'm not sure if there are any such flights that are international.

Comment: Examples? The 100 seat threshold cuts off a lot of re-purposed planes. Antonov made a lot of < 100 seat airplanes, and there was no hard line between military and civil in the old Soviet days. Very visible in the 3rd world, but < 100 seats. The AVRO York, Boeing 377, Tu-104 and Tu-114 were civil fuselages with military wings. The French made piston engined airliners, and the British did (and turbo props). But the reason Airbus exists is that large, jet, airliners require big money. Boeing won in USA, bought-out McDonnell Douglas. Lockheed & Martin got out of airliners.

Comment: Ah well, I found out. Those jets are all out of commission now. I know there were some jets that were initially modified to be used as military jets and later used as commercial airliners till around 1980's.

Comment: And one of then even crashed in a mid air collision.